# How to create a file with a stored procedure in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

i am trying to create a file with a stored procedure in T-SQL. I need this to trigger an event in another program. Could anybody help me with that? I didn't find much on google that really helped me.
I would like to have an empty file named "newWCC.dd". Path doesn't matter yet because I just want to know how I even create it

Comment: Could you please elaborate more

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create text files from SQL Server using BCP utility as follows

```
declare @cmd varchar(1000)
declare @filepath varchar(500) = 'c:\temp\samplefile.dd'
SET @cmd = 'bcp "select 1 as test" queryout "' + @filepath + '" -c -UTF8 -T -Slocalhost'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

We can even remove the SELECT part from @cmd

```
declare @cmd varchar(1000)
declare @filepath varchar(500) = 'c:\temp\samplefile.dd'
SET @cmd = 'bcp "" queryout "' + @filepath + '" -c -UTF8 -T -Slocalhost'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

You can check for a more complex usage on SQL tutorial [SQL Server BCP Utility to generate script file for stored procedures](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/bcp-and-sp_helptext-to-script-store-procedures-into-seperate-files.aspx)

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What does all the stuff in set @cmd do?

Comment: Actually this method is used to export data from SQL Server to text files. So I only used a dummy SQL Select there

Comment: @Eralper Hi, this is great info even though I am not asking the question. But I have one question. If you run this on the SSMS on your machine, connecting to the SQL Server on a different machine, will the file be created on the C drive of your computer or on the Server's computer? Do you need any extra privillege to run this?

Comment: @Eralper I used U:\newWCC.dd as path. It doesn't create the file. I connected it as an external drive with my server so it should work but it doesn't. Do you know why?

Comment: Hi @DVT, the SQL Server instance is important here not the SSMS. The file will be created on the folder referenced to the SQL Server instance. So the C: drive will be the local drive of the server not the client where SSMS is installed. You will require permissions on the target drive for write in this case. Please check the write permissions of the SQL Server services on the folder.

Comment: Hi @VerwirrterAzubi, please the share external drive for everyone with read/write permissions. If the script is successfull to generate the file on the folder, you can grant write permissions of SQL Server service users on the folder

Comment: @Eralper I don't think that it's a smart idea to give everyone read and write. That would be just another vulnerability in the network of my company. I would need the exact user that the server uses the execute procedures.

Comment: Please check article http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/create-folder-sql-sys-xp_create_subdir-extended-stored-procedure.aspx where SQLServerMSSQLUser  user is granted write permission for such a task on target folder.

Comment: Why a query on specific database instead 'select 1' is not working?-> EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

declare 'at'cmd varchar(1000)
declare'at'filepath varchar(500) = 'F:\teste\samplefile.txt'
SET 'at'cmd = 'bcp "SELECT TOP 1 globalid FROM teste.dbo.teste_EVW
WHERE globalid IS NOT NULL" queryout "' + 'at'filepath + '" -c -UTF8 -T -Slocalhost'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'at'cmd

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;
RECONFIGURE;